# a nicer way for if (!true) {return;}

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I have a big chuck of code witch looks like this

```
if(!Click(By.linkText("HR Development"))){return;}
if(!Click(By.linkText("ISTQB Agile Tester Extension ( 1/2)"))){return;}
```

The idea is that the Click function returns true if the click succeeds and false otherwise.

There are also other functions like this outside the click function

does someone know a nicer way to get the same result?

Comment: `if (!Click(By.linkText("HR Development")) || !Click(By.linkText("ISTQB Agile Tester Extension ( 1/2)")) return;`?

Answer (score 0):

So why not just

```
return boolean_expression();
```

whatever that expression evaluates, gets returned.

e.g.

```
if (foo == bar) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

can simply be

```
return (foo == bar);
```

Comment: Becourse it should only return if the statement is false and it should go to the next statement if the return value is true

Comment: Then you need the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You could recast to the equivalent

```
if (
    !Click(By.linkText("HR Development")) ||
    !Click(By.linkText("ISTQB Agile Tester Extension ( 1/2)"))
){
    return;
}
```

Note that evaluation of `||` stops once the result is known. (This is called *short-circuitting*.)

Littering your functions with many `return;` statements can make debugging difficult as it can become difficult to set reliable breakpoints.

Comment: I know that i can sorten it like that, but the idea is that it should stop if the statement is false en else go tot the next statement. I can have 100 lines like that under eatchother

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that this is a nicer way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a big chuck of code witch [sic] looks like this

That's your problem.  It looks like you've written one click handling class for many events.

Another idea might be to create individual handlers for events and have custom behavior as needed.  That would be a more object-oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `boolean` variables out your conditions, and test with a `||` (or) operator:

```
boolean foo = !Click(By.linkText("HR Development"));
boolean bar = !Click(By.linkText("ISTQB Agile Tester Extension ( 1/2)"));

if (foo || bar) {
    return;
}
```

It's clean, and if needed, you can add as many variables as you want.

Comment: The point is that if In this case Click(By.linkText("HR Development")) returns false it is impossible to execute Click(By.linkText("ISTQB Agile Tester Extension ( 1/2)")); so your solution won't work